# uint64_t выдаёт результат как int32_t

Tags: c++, c

Пробегаюсь по циклу и никак не могу понять как это получается?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DEBUG 1

#define NUMSYMBOLS 24
#define BUFLEN (NUMSYMBOLS * 8)

int loop(uint64_t numb)
{
    debugprint("numb", numb, 0);
    uint64_t res = 0;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < numb; i++)
    {
        res += i;
        // debugprint("res", res, i % 1000000);
    }

    unsigned long long big = 1844674407370955161;

    debugprint("big", big, 0);
    debugprint("ULLONG_MAX", ULLONG_MAX, 0);
    debugprint("res", res, 0);
    return res;
};

void debugprint(char *name, unsigned long long res, int go)
{
    if (DEBUG == 0 || go != 0)
        return;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    memset(buf, 0, BUFLEN);
    sprintf(buf, "%d", res);
    printf("\n%s\nbits:\t%d\n", name, sizeof(res) * 8);
    printf("val:\t%s\n", buf);
};

void main()
{
    loop(5000000);
};
```

Вывод программы:

```
numb
bits:   64
val:    5000000

big
bits:   64
val:    -1717986919

ULLONG_MAX
bits:   64
val:    -1

res
bits:   64
val:    1642668640
```

Почему значения не unsigned long long???

```
PS D:\GitHub\loop_speed> gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

Comment: При печати `uint64_t` нужен формат не `%d` (это печать 32-бит целого), а [см. этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225648/7286264) (или просто `%llu`, но `uint64_t` надо привести к `unsigned long long` (те же яйца, вид сбоку), т.е. `sprintf(buf, "%llu", res);` (и не забывайте, что длинные константы при передаче надо сопровождать суффиксами, например `123456789987654ULL`))

Comment: @avp размер типа числа выставляет компилятор автоматически. `L` ставить не надо. А `U` - надо.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, это от компилятора зависит. В gcc 7.5 можно ничего не ставить, по типу приемника соображает и ругается при overflow

Comment: @avp стандарт **6.4.4.1 Integer constants**: *"The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented."* Тип целочисленной константы является первым из соответствующего списка, в котором может быть представлено ее значение. `Suffix=none: int -> long int -> long long int` ; `Suffix=L: long int -> long long int`

Comment: @avp Спасибо! Сразу начал понимать чяднт

Comment: @AlexGlebe, из поведения gcc следует, что в этом мире еще остались умные люди

Answer (score 0):

Да, я не подумал что функция обязана вернуть инт...

```
int loop(uint64_t numb)
{
    return (uint64_t)999999999999999;
}
```

Ну, сам себе буратино, спасибо за ответы!